# How to get max date of group of rows

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am looking to get the latest date of a select statement inside a select statement. I am using Hibernate, so there are limitations to normal MySQL such as not being able to have the select statement in the from area or inside MAX.

Here is a test structure:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  username varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  locationId int(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE UserRecords (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  recordDate datetime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO User VALUES ('test',1);
INSERT INTO User VALUES ('test2',2);
INSERT INTO User VALUES ('test3',1);

INSERT INTO UserRecords VALUES (null,'test','2018-02-10 14:29:40');
INSERT INTO UserRecords VALUES (null,'test2','2018-03-11 12:21:10');
INSERT INTO UserRecords VALUES (null,'test3','2018-05-18 11:11:15');
INSERT INTO UserRecords VALUES (null,'test','2018-06-20 16:58:50');
```

This is what I am after and works regularly, but doesn't work in Hibernate:

```
SELECT 
   u.locationId, 
   MAX(
      SELECT 
         MAX(ur.recordDate) 
      FROM
         UserRecords
      WHERE 
         ur.username=u.username
   )
FROM 
   User u
GROUP BY
   u.locationId
```

The closest I can get is by just listing the max dates of each user and then have to parse them after.

```
SELECT 
    u.locationId, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT('''',
          SELECT 
             MAX(ur.recordDate) 
          FROM
             UserRecords
          WHERE 
             ur.username=u.username
       , '''')
    )
 FROM 
    User u
 GROUP BY
    u.locationId
```

This is really stripped down, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to get the max record date per location id which can be achieved joining nest subQueries

#### location ID's max record date

```
SELECT
  u.locationId,
  Max(urRecordDate.maxRecordDate)
FROM User u
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
     ur.username,
     MAX(ur.recordDate) AS maxRecordDate
   FROM UserRecords ur
   GROUP BY ur.username) AS urRecordDate
    ON u.username = urRecordDate.username
GROUP BY u.locationId
```

#### Users max record date and locationId

```
SELECT
  u.locationId,
  urRecordDate.maxRecordDate
FROM User u
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
     ur.username,
     MAX(ur.recordDate) AS maxRecordDate
   FROM UserRecords ur
   GROUP BY ur.username) AS urRecordDate
    ON u.username = urRecordDate.username
```

[using native SQL queries in hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating)

Comment: Note that this method can return multiple records per group if the MAX(recordDate) value within a group is the same.. Because it does not handle ties.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use native SQL queries in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
select u.locationId, ur.recordDate
FROM User u
JOIN UserRecords ur on (ur.username = u.username)
ORDER BY ur.recordDate desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need the max date as an alternate returned column, not a filter on the main records.

Comment: What do you mean by 'alternate returned column'?